# "IsRequired" not working for Input.Text of Adaptive Card in MsTeams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to add **required** validation to check whether the comment box is empty or not. I have checked on multiple places and blogs to make it work but some how validation is not working at all in Teams. When i'm using Designer of Adaptive card it is working as expected.

Below is the **JSON** code i'm using in my teams bot.

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.3",
"body": [
           {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "label": "Comments",
        "style": "text",
        "isMultiline": true,
        "id": "MultiLineVal",
        "isRequired": true,
        "errorMessage": "required"
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit"
    }
]
```

}

> Designer Screen grab

[image: designer]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this reference on input validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/input-validation) and notice that it's referrring to Adaptive Cards 1.3 and above, whereas, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#support-for-adaptive-cards), Teams is currently a bit behind, supporting up to Adaptive Cards 1.2 only. The products, while related, are different and have different release cycles - hopefully 1.3 will come soon for Teams.